# How to use google code jquery $.jsonp

Tags: jquery, jsonp, google-code

I have several questions about using this.

1) I need to download the `jquery.jsonp-2.1.4.min.js` from google code but in which folder should I put it? (I am using xampp) In `C:\xampp` or `C:\xampp\htdocs`?

2) What should I write so that I can pass some strings from a web's using `$.jsonp` to my local server? What should I change in the "data" input to pass the variable `str`?

```
$.jsonp({
    "url": "http://localhost/server.php",
    "data": {
        "alt": "json-in-script"
    },
    "success": function(userProfile) {
        alert("ha"); // handle user profile here 
    },
    "error": function(d,msg) {
        alert("Could not find user ");
    }
});
```

3) How can I get the variable "str" in the php page?

```
<?php echo str; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of jQuery have JSONP support built in. A separate JSONP library is no longer necessary.

You can use it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': "/path/to/your/endpoint.php?callback=?",
    'dataType': 'jsonp',
    'data': ...
});
```

The values in `data` are passed as URL arguments; as such, they will show up in `$_GET` if you're using PHP. Note that the result MUST be formatted as JSON, wrapped in a function specified in the callback. The appropriate code will probably look something like:

```
print $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($result) . ');';
```

Comment: Yet what should I do if I am using $.jsonp
it seems that the data:{name="a"}  will include the name in url argument.... which means I can use ||echo $_GET['name']|| ?